# What does it mean when two beans specialize the same Managed bean

Tags: java, javabeans

I am working on a Java project using Gradle and when I try running this application I will receive the error:

```
11:51:00.304 DEBUG org.jboss.weld.BootstrapTracker.start() @82 - START bootstrap > validateBeans
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.InconsistentSpecializationException: WELD-001401: Two beans cannot specialize the same bean Managed Bean [class com.lmco.compass.rebar.util.ScopeManager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateSpecialization(Validator.java:502)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:492)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:496)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:93)
        at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:804)
        at com.lmco.compass.rebar.ApplicationMain.run(ApplicationMain.java:120)
        at com.lmco.compass.rebar.ApplicationMain.main(ApplicationMain.java:70)
11:51:00.409 INFO  com.lmco.compass.commons.time.LeapSecondManager.loadProvider() @125 - No leap second provider found, using system default
```

This has been a big pain trying to debug for me. But I'll start be asking the general question of what does it mean if two beans specialize a single managed one and what could be a common reason someone may get this error. The answers I found on google to this question didn't really clear things up for me, so if answers could be put in as simplest of terms as possible that would be swell.